# Return a List of Counted, Unique Items

Tags: excel, r

I've been given a file with hundreds of thousands of values, inconsistently formatted in a .CSV file. Structure might resemble:

A,B,C,D
E,F
G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O
P,Q,R,S

And so on.

All that I need to do is to a) list the unique values and b) count instances of same. Happy to do this in R, Excel or any other tool recommended.

Normally, I'd use something like Google Docs' =UNIQUE and =COUNT functions, but the spreadsheet is too big to load there. Nor have I found exact equivalents in Excel, oddly enough.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should work (in R):

```
# Emulate your file
cat('A,B,C,D\nB,D\nA,A,F,Q,F\n', file='foo.csv')

x <- scan('foo.csv', what='', sep=',')
table(x)
#x
#A B C D F Q 
#3 2 1 2 2 1
```

Comment: Bless you, that worked like a champ! Wrote it to a .csv using write.csv() and I'm off to the races. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you said "any other tool":

```
%perl -F',' -a -n -e 'chomp, $count{$_}++ foreach (@F); END {print "$_: $count{$_}\n" foreach sort keys %count;}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to import the data into R? Something like read.csv should work...
Without getting into apply-type functions, you can do a simple loop to search for the counts of unique values (e.g. letters):

```
set.seed(1)

OBJ <- LETTERS[round(runif(1000, min=1, max=26))]
VALS <- unique(OBJ)
VALS
COUNTS <- rep(0*length(VALS))
for(i in seq(VALS)){
    COUNTS[i] <- length(which(OBJ==VALS[i]))
}

data.frame(VALS, COUNTS)
```